# Add a perl project in Komodo

Tags: perl, debugging, batch-file, komodo

I have an old perl(5.12.3) project, which I would like to debug in the komodo 3.0.1 environment (temporarely i have only this old version).
 The project is a multiple module project, with a three like structure:

```
Root
    core
        module1.pm
        ...
    external
        ext_module.pm
        ...
    caller.bat
```

The project start point is the .bat file. Would it be possible to add and debug it in komodo? Any suggestion are appreciated.

```
set PERL_EXIST=0
perl -version >nul 2>&1 && ( set PERL_EXIST=1 )
if %PERL_EXIST% EQU 0 (
rem if perl doesn't exist give an error message and finish
echo.
echo ERROR:     Perl %PERL_DIR% is missing
set PERL_EXIST=
set MY_EXIT_CODE=1
goto EXIT
)
.
.
.
#perl starts here
use core::FirstModule;
use Cwd qw(getcwd chdir);
use Switch;

use core::FirstModule;
use Env qw(PATH VAR_1 PROJ_VERSION CORE_LOC );

# adapt the environment to point to main folder
$ENV{'CORE_LOC'}=~s/[\\\/]?[^\\\/]*$//;
if ($ENV{'CORE_LOC'}=~/[\\\/].*$/i) {
$ENV{'CORE_LOC'} =~s/[\\\/]?[^\\\/]*$//;
.
.
.
.
push @INC,$sourceDir;
$hFirstModule = core::FirstModule->new("object properties");
$hFirstModule->checkDir($dir_version);
```

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. Is the batch file calling Perl, i.e. is there a `perl -Mcore::module1 -e ' ...'` or another call to the perl interpreter? If yes, you can add Perl environment variables for debugging that tell Perl to use a remote debugger on a certain port. Then you need to tell Komodo to listen on hat port, and it will grab the connection and handle debugging as a remote debugging client for the Perl process. There is stuff about that in the Komodo documentation, but I don't know if it already works in Komodo 3.

Comment: Please include the part of the batch file that calls Perl, and what platform you are running on. The version of Perl is not really relevant here.

Comment: This is the oldest one I can find, for Komodo IDE 4.4: http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/debugperl.html

Comment: ActiveState perl, on windows7. The calls are made for multiple Perl modules, and they are called as core::MyModule->new(). Forgot to mention that it's an OOP project.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Is the .bat file in Perl? How do you call that? Perl modules are not executable.

Comment: Mostly Perl, there are also some echo's, set's and go to's

Comment: Please show it. You can [edit] the question to add it. If you're not comfortable showing it, replace names.

Comment: It's a 600 line code, what should i show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118012/discussion-between-simbabque-and-john-doe).

Comment: Runnin' on a proxied connection, not able to acces the link.

Comment: OK. Show the first maybe ten lines. And if those don't contain Perl (or a call to `perl`) then find one and get maybe five lines up and down please.

Comment: If you run it on the same machine as your Komodo, you can follow the docs I linked earlier. Do what it says in _Debugging Perl Remotely_ and use the Windows examples. Put the env variables (the `SET` stuff) at the very top. Have Komodo runnning when you call the batch file.

Comment: @simbabque pretty much got all the key points.  Only issue that might arise is that Komodo 3.0 is just too old and won't support Perl remote debugging.  You might want to try it on a newer version first where you KNOW it works then copy those steps with Komodo 3.